# Normal arrows using Charter

Tags: fonts, arrows

I am writing a thesis in Charter font for both normal and math mode, however I do not like the font that is applied for the arrows.

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{O}_X:\beta & \longrightarrow \mathfrak{Rings}\\
               D(f) & \longmapsto     A_f
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

should look like this:

[image: Charter style arrows]

Is it possible to use Charter in mathmode but keeping the "normal" arrows such as:

[image]

I am quite new in messing with fonts, so please forgive me if I am missing something trivial.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the Computer Modern math symbol font for the arrows; one also has to change `\relbar` to use the Computer Modern minus sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmarrows}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{cmarrows}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmminus}{\mathbin}{cmarrows}{"00}
\DeclareRobustCommand\relbar{\mathrel{\smash\cmminus}}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftrightarrow}{\mathrel}{cmarrows}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftarrow}{\mathrel}{cmarrows}{"20}
   \let\gets=\leftarrow
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightarrow}{\mathrel}{cmarrows}{"21}
   \let\to=\rightarrow
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mapstochar}{\mathrel}{cmarrows}{"37}
   \def\mapsto{\mapstochar\rightarrow}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{O}_X:\beta & \longrightarrow \mathfrak{Rings}\\
               D(f) & \longmapsto     A_f
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative could be loading `old-arrows` (with less prominent arrow tips):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{old-arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{O}_X:\beta & \longrightarrow \mathfrak{Rings}\\
               D(f) & \longmapsto     A_f
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]